# How can I make the last row of a datatable take up all the columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I am creating a DataTable in C#. I have the table set up with a certain number of rows and columns. The last row however, I want it to take up the entire table. How can I make the last row take up the entire data table? The table is bounded to a DataGrid in a xaml file. I'm not sure if I am suppose to make changes in the C# file or the xaml file.

```
public DataTable TestTable { get; set; }

private void SetUpTable()
{
    this.TestTable = new DataTable();

    this.TestTable.Columns.Add("Players");
    this.TestTable.Columns.Add("Health");
    this.TestTable.Columns.Add("Power");
    this.TestTable.Columns.Add("Speed");

    this.TestTable.Rows.Add("Player1");            
    this.TestTable.Rows.Add("Player2");
    this.TestTable.Rows.Add("Player3");
    this.TestTable.Rows.Add("Winner");

    this.PopulateTable();
}



<DataGrid
     filtergrid:DataGridExtensions.UseBackgroundWorkerForFiltering="True"
     filtergrid:DataGridExtensions.IsFilterVisible="True"
     filtergrid:DataGridExtensions.IsClearButtonVisible="False"
     AutoGenerateColumns="True"
     ItemsSource="{Binding TestTable, Mode=Twoway}"
     Grid.Row="3"
     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
     MaxHeight="400"
     MinHeight="100"
     MaxWidth="750"
     MinWidth="750"
     Margin="5, 10, 0, 0"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
     EnableRowVirtualization="True"
     IsReadOnly="True"
     CanUserAddRows="False">
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: You are in edit mode which add a blank row to allow adding more data.  Turn edit mode off.

Comment: XAML means WPF?  Tag it appropriately.  Show your relative XAML.  You have Player1-3 and Winner in the Health column.  That seems a bit off.

Comment: Sorry this was just a mockup cause I didn't want to use the actual code. Just made some edits